# Error installing pyinstaller behind a proxy firewall - secondary installation of setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install pyinstaller behind a proxy for my company.  I use the standard "pip install -- proxy userid:password@companyproxy.net:port pyinstaller" and that all works great.  The problem is that within the pyinstaller installation, it tries to install the setuptools package also, but when pip calls that from https://pypi.org/simple it apparently doesn't give it the credentials for the proxy and the installation of setuptools fails which causes my pyinstaller package install to fail.

Has anyone else ran into this problem and have suggestions for how to fix this so I can get pyinstaller on my machine?  I actually already have the setuptools package in my site-packages so I don't need that package but I don't know if I can somehow tell pyinstaller to not try to install setuptools.

```
C:\Users\dt24358\Downloads>pip install pyinstaller-3.4.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\dt24358\downloads\pyinstaller-3.4.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\dt24358\python.exe c:\users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix c:\temp\pip-build-env-8cil1gjv\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
    Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x047903B0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x047904D0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x047905F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04790450>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04790350>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/setuptools/
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools

  ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\dt24358\python.exe c:\users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix c:\temp\pip-build-env-8cil1gjv\overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel" failed with error code 1 in None
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In command line  / terminal please set proxy before executing that command.

**Command as follows:**

- If in Linux / Unix / Mac

  > export HTTP_PROXY=http://userid:password@companyproxy.net:port  export
  >   HTTPS_PROXY=http://userid:password@companyproxy.net:port
- If in Windows

  > set HTTP_PROXY=http://userid:password@companyproxy.net:port set
  >   HTTPS_PROXY=http://userid:password@companyproxy.net:port

This will solve your problem. You can set those as your environment variable, so that you never have to worry about it.